# chrome debugger: clicking exception link in console opens file in new tab instead of cross-linking into source file

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, coffeescript, console, source-maps

I have the chrome debugger open showing both the console and the sources tab. I am debugging a meteor.js application and am getting an exception in the console that displays a file link with a line number in the stack trace.

[image: stack trace and chrome window configuration]

I swear when I used to click these it would cross-link to the specific line within the sources tab. But now it is simply just opening the file in a new tab in chrome:

[image: file opened in new tab]

I am using coffee-script and have source maps enabled, and doing this all within the latest Ubuntu LTS and Chrome beta.

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3655

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Meteor folks are working on this: http://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3655

Comment: All credit for this answer goes to @mutil. I just copied it to an answer so it could be accepted. I made this a community wiki so I don't get undeserved reputation.